# PHPUnit not producing records

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

For some reason PHPUnit has stopped producing coverage records and I don't know why. It was producing them yesterday just fine. It still runs unit tests as expected and they pass/fail correctly, but it no longer respects the `--coverage` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually caused by an upgrade to OSX. When OSX upgrades it replaces the currently installed PHP-cli bin with a default one. This can cause a problem if you've re-mapped `php` to refer to another binary installed with `MacPorts`. Be sure to look for a warning `XDebug not installed`, or similar, which will indicate that this has happened.

Should be noted: this will happen any time that `XDebug` is removed as an extension, not just in OSX. However because OSX is particularly destructive when it comes to resetting defaults (I actually have the MacPorts `httpd` server mapped to a different name so that it won't ever override the correct Apache settings) it is worth noting here.